# Using the Rank Function In Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2010, rank

Sorry if this has been answered and I feel it may have but I am struggling to find an answer that helps me to the point of success.

I have a basic spreadsheet for time trial results. The spreadsheet is for both men and women. Basically, points are awarded for the quickest times throughout the entire competitors on 30 second intervals which is fine (Cloumn N)...(I have managed this)

My question is - On top of this the top 7 men in ranked position is awarded additional bonus points and the top 3 (only because there is normally less women attending the events than men) women are also additional awarded bonus points.

I have set up a column to specify M or F (Column C) when a competitor is added, and also using RANK

```
=IF(G7=0,0,RANK(G7,$G$6:$G$36,1)-COUNTIF($G$6:$G$36,0))
```

on the times - Column K

But I am really struggling with how to use a formula to extract the top 7 men and top 3 women and award the points. Ie there will be a 1st place man - 7th but also a 1st place woman - 3rd. So in essence is there any way I can extract the two sets of rankings from the identification of F and M from the appropriate column.

At the moment I can only get the a basic ranking and using an IF(AND) statement I can return results to apply the bonus points if the conditions are matched but this doesnt help with identifying the rankings according to Male (1st-7th) or Female (1st-3rd)

[image]

You can also see on my screen dump that although I havent added the formula for assigning the female points that because of the conditions been met I dont have bonus points awarded for 5th place because I set sex to F which I was hoping someone could also help me with

Sorry for waffling but I have been toiling with this 3 days now and I am just going in circles

Really appreciate any reply

Answer (score 1):

Just use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(G6=0,0,COUNTIFS(C:C,C6,G:G,"<" & G6,G:G,"<>0")+1)
```

This will rank the like entries in C, thus giving two 1st, one male and one female.

To add for the Club just add another condition:

```
=IF(G6=0,0,COUNTIFS(C:C,C6,G:G,"<" & G6,G:G,"<>0",B:B,B6)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott - didnt expect an answer so quick. Im a novice so please accept my apologies. What I actually want to do is: as you can see I have sorted my club column. Is there any way to rank the men and then the women within each club. So in essence you will 1st-4th for men and 1st-4th for women (varying on how many turn up for any given club) in each and every club that takes part. Even if it is in multiple columns or a table. I also tried the answer above but it still wont give me the first 7 fastest men and first third fastest women - and it also ranks a non compete. Thanks il keep trying

Comment: @JMcBrien this formula is designed to start in row 6 if not starting in row 6 you need to change all the `6` to the row in which you first place the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much - its working now - really appreciate the help. Thankyou =)

Comment: @JMcBrien please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  And delete your other post as it is now a duplicate of this one.