# COUNTIFS Function

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, rank, countif, sumifs

can anyone help..
Trying to rank the times - quickest first but how do I do this and exclude the time 00:00:00 (ie a non finish or didnt show for race)

Currently using

=COUNTIFS(B$6:B$36, B16, H$6:H$36, "<"&H16)+1

but this ranks 00:00:00 as being the quickest which I want to exclude and the next quickest non-zero time to be the 1st position[image]

Comment: My formula on your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231987/using-the-rank-function-in-excel ignored the 0s.  If it did not work then you time is a fraction of a second and not a true 0.  You just need to keep adding conditions to the COUNTIFS() to group the like ones together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the Rank Function In Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231987/using-the-rank-function-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

=IF(H16=0,"DNF",COUNTIFS(B$6:B$36,B16,H$6:H$36,"<"&H16)+1-COUNTIFS(B$6:B$36,B16,H$6:H$36,0))                                                                We edited your formula which you entered into the cell F16.

We hope that we understood your question properly.